# Unreliable errors while multithreading in SFML for C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, graphics, sfml

I am trying to make a basic game in c++ using the SFML library. For this game, I want a thread
drawing at a fixed rate and another thread checking for input as often as possible. The first problem I encountered was that the SFML library does not allow for window to be active on multiple threads. A simple fix for this was found by just deactivating the window in the main thread. The next problem that I have not yet found a fix for is that I cannot seem to check for input on my main thread (In this scenario).

This code is very unreliable. I can get two different error messages, or an infinite loop. What should happen is an infinite loop that can be closed with the escape key, and if you press d it prints a message.

The library I am using is libsfml-dev

My compile arguments are as follows: g++ test.cpp -pthread -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "");

using namespace std;

void *func(void *threadid) {

    cout << "New thread." << endl; 
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // In the actual implementation, this would be replaced with draw methods
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape)) { 
            window.close();
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main() {

    // Needed so that window is only active on a single thread
    window.setActive(false);

    // Create new thread
    pthread_t threads[1];
    int val;
    val = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, func, (void *)1);
    
    cout << "Main thread." << endl;
    
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) {
            cout << "D button pressed." << endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Error Number 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fGXb.png)
PS: XInitThreads doesn't help
[Error Number 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ifcpb.png)
Looks like an error from my X server

Comment: I do not use SFML but IIRC  its based on OpenGL and in OpenGL You have to use `wglMakeCurrent` on Windows or its counterparts for other OS ... before any GL stuff execution after any thread change. So try to look for similar function inside SFML that handles that ... Also if you use shared variables/classes then you need to add locks or lockless mechanism to synchronize the threads to avoid collisions and access violations because of them.

Comment: From quick look at your errors I was right you need to add `X_GLXMakeCurrent` call to each thread and just guessing `XInintThreads` is encapsulating it in SFML (and or do similar stuff for other parts of SFML not just OpenGL) so you should add that first and then add the MakeCurrent if still needed ... Sorry for just commenting only but I do not feel quallified to make an answer for SFML/Linux environment as I do not code in it and all this is just my educated guess ...

Comment: It's all good I appreciate any feedback.